# Knockout sortable lists in a sortable parent list

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I understand we can do separate sortable list in knockout according to

jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QWgRF/

but i m trying to do these lists in a sortable parent list.

Metric Group 1:
Metric 1
Metric 2
Metric 3

Metric Group 2:
Metric 4
Metric 5
Metric 7
Metric 6

Metric Group 3:
Metric 8

what i m trying to do is MetricGroup 1, 2, 3 are belong to a master list which is sortable, so i can change the order of the groups. I also need to drage Metric 4 to Group 3, so i can regrouping in some ways, in addition, i need to drag Metric 4 outside of the Groups so it can form new Group 4, that is, make a child to a parent in the parent list.

i m trying to use the same sortable binding handlers, but not working somehow, is this possible or is there any examples i can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `connectClass` option on a sortable binding to restrict which other sortable's that you can drop the item into.

The markup would look something like:

```
<ul data-bind="sortable: { data: parents, connectClass: 'parentItem' }">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <ul data-bind="sortable: { data: items, connectClass: 'childItem' }">
            <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The connect class is added automatically to the element that is bound, so you do not need to do anything else.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/xJYPh/